# Extract specific conditions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mecab

I create python code like this, but it does not work well.
(result not return)

I want to extract just "動詞" "名詞" "形容詞"

Do you have any idea?

Thank you so much.

```
m = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
for result in results:
 #     word = m.parse(result['text'])

    word = [line.split()[0] for line in m.parse(result['text']).splitlines() if "名詞" in line.split()[-1] 
                                for line in m.parse(result['text']).splitlines() if "動詞" in line.split()[-1] 
                                     for line in m.parse(result['text']).splitlines() if "形容詞" in line.split()[-1]]
    result['mecab'] = word
```

Comment: Define "does not work well"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing what you are trying to do. I assume you have a results list. You try to extract a specific set of characters from a each result element in your results list. Then you need to do:

```py
m = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
for result in results:
    result_text = result["text"]
    result_text = m.parse(result_text)
    text_lines = result_text.splitlines()
    word = None
    for line in text_lines:
        if "名詞" in line:
            word = "名詞"
        elif "動詞" in line:
            word = "動詞"
        elif "形容詞" in line:
            word = "形容詞"
    if word is not None:
        result['mecab'] = word
```

Or something along these lines

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if you use data that has been parsed. You should use [fugashi](https://github.com/polm/fugashi), which is also a MeCab wrapper.

```
import fugashi
tagger = fugashi.Tagger()
nodes = tagger.parseToNodeList("図書館から赤い本を借りた")
goodpos = ['名詞', '動詞', '形容詞']
nodes = [nn.surface for nn in nodes if nn.feature.pos1 in goodpos]
# => ['図書', '赤い', '本', '借り']
```